# error is not printed in form validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i created three scaffold in rails. project has  one to many relation with stage and stage has one to many relation with task. In model validation of project and stage is working but model validation of task error is not printed in task form.

routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
 resources :stages do
  resources :tasks 
  end
end
```

task form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: [@project, @stage, @task] do |form| %>
  <% if task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_with (model: task, url: [@project, @stage, @task] do |form| %>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value